# deploying docker compose to aws ecs using x-aws-cloudformation for subnets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy a 2 tier architecture aws deployment using docker compose into aws ecs.

From everything that I have read and found, it seems that I can use x-aws-cloudformation overly to use specific subnets in my docker compose build.  So, this is what I have:

```
version: '3.8'

x-aws-vpc: "vpc-0f64c8ba9cb5bb10f"

services:
  osticket:
    container_name: osticket-web
    image: osticket/osticket
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    container_name: osticket-db
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: osticket
      MYSQL_USER: osticket
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    expose:
      - "3306"
      
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    OsticketService:
      Properties:
        NetworkConfiguration:
          AwsvpcConfiguration:
            Subnets:
              - subnet-093223fe760e52016 #public subnet-1
              - subnet-08120f88feb55e3f1 #public subnet-2
    DbService:
      Properties:
        NetworkConfiguration:
          AwsvpcConfiguration:
            Subnets:
              - subnet-0c68a298227d9c2e8 #private subnet-1
              - subnet-042cae15125ba9b1b #private subnet-2
```

As you can see in my compose file, I have 2 services, osticket and db. In docker compose convert cloudformation output, it shows as OsticketService and DbService.  The major problem is that for each service in the cloudformation template, it shows all of the subnets in each service instead of what I provided in the docker compose file. So, when I try to deploy it, I get the following error:

```
A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: 41880961-a4d5-4c15-9315-603acdef26f5; Proxy: null)
```

I'm not sure where I need to make the changes to get this working.  Please let me know if you need to see the cloudformation template and I will upload it.

Thank you.